# Calculating geometry size as a circle, and combining that data

Tags: geometry, shapely

Given a way geometry (from OSM), I would like to convert them to "circles" - a center point + radius guaranteed to contain the whole object. Plus I would need a set of functions to perform various union operations:

- calculate centroid (already done using [shapely](https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.representative_point))
- calculate smallest radius that encloses the whole way
- be able to combine two circles, produce a new center+radius circle that contains both.
- be able to combine one circle with one point (find a new center + radius that contain previous circle and the node)
- (simple case) combine two nodes into a circle

Is there a (preferably Python) library to do this?  Ideally the library should calculate surface distance rather than direct distance for the radius.

Comment: i think a circle, enclosing an arbitrary shape, will be the circle enclosing the minimal bounding rectangle (mbr). So you should find your solution by construction the circle as a circumcircle (? "Umkreis" in German) around that MBR.

Comment: @AndreasMüller thanks, that's a interesting thought! Is there an algo to measure "width/height" along the earth's curvature for a given bbox?  The "width" of such bbox depends on its latitude too, so its not a trivial "west minus east".   Hm, spoke too soon - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59087/how-to-calculate-the-size-a-bounding-box